# Why would the answer be $20\choose 2$?

Tags: combinatorics

> If everyone in a room shakes hands with everybody else, how many handshakes take place in a room of $20$ people?

I understand it as $19+18+17+...+1$, but it is supposed to be solved by $20\choose 2$. How do you get that from the question?

Comment: Each handshake involves $2$ people out of $20$

Comment: You are presumably aware that those are the same number?

Comment: @Joffan Yes $\!$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the set of all handshakes. Each element is uniquely determined by the two people that shaked hands, so there are as many handshakes as there are pairs of people. How many pairs are there? Well, ${20 \choose 2 }= \frac{20!}{2!\cdot 18!}$